# Change Flask IP without arguments

Tags: python, flask

How can I change my flask app to run on its local ip *without* using a command line arg?

I am using argparse in a module and it crys when I pass --host=192.168.1.99 as a command line arg

```
(asd) carrier@carrier:~/public_html/asd$ printenv | grep FLASK
FLASK_APP=/home/carrier/public_html/asd/do/autoapp.py
FLASK_DEBUG=1
(asd) carrier@carrier:~/public_html/asd$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "autoapp"
 * Forcing debug mode on
/home/carrier/public_html/asd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_debugtoolbar/panels/sqlalchemy.py:2: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.sqlalchemy is deprecated, use flask_sqlalchemy instead.
  from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import get_debug_queries, SQLAlchemy
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
/home/carrier/public_html/asd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_debugtoolbar/panels/sqlalchemy.py:2: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.sqlalchemy is deprecated, use flask_sqlalchemy instead.
  from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import get_debug_queries, SQLAlchemy
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 131-221-175
```

I am not familiar with using 'flask run' to run my apps but i followed a guide. normally i would do python manage.py runserver. any help is appreciated.

my code is a direct clone from this: https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to update a section of lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py

```
@click.option('--host', '-h', default='192.168.1.99',    #127.0.0.1',
               help='The interface to bind to.')
```

Comment: it it worst solution - don't change code in oryginal flask code.